# When I filtering a queryset according to created date Postgres is taking 100% cpu and it never ends

Tags: postgresql, django-models

I have come across a problem when working on a simple project. When I executed a query the Postgres is taking 100% CPU and it never stops (I had to kill the process 2 minutes after).

These are my models related to this issue

```
class ProjectUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField('Username', blank=False, db_index=True, max_length=255, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField('Email', blank=True, null=True, db_index=True, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField('First Name', max_length=128)
    last_name = models.CharField('Last Name', max_length=128, blank=True)
    nick_name = models.CharField('Stage Name', max_length=128, null=True, blank=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField('Staff Status', default=False,
                                   help_text='Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.',
                                   db_index=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField('Active', default=True,
                                    help_text=('Designates whether this user should be treated as '
                                               'active. Deselect this instead of deleting accounts.'), db_index=True)
                                         default=SIGN_UP_SOURCE_CHOICES.regular)
    gender = models.IntegerField('Gender', choices=[1, 2], default=1,
                                 db_index=True)
    phone = models.CharField('Phone Number', null=True, blank=True, max_length=15)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField('Created Date', auto_now_add=True)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField('Modified Date', auto_now=True)




class UserConnect(models.Model):
    from_user = models.ForeignKey('users.ProjectUser', related_name='connect_from_user', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    to_user = models.ForeignKey('users.ProjectUser', related_name='connect_to_user', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField('Created Date', auto_now_add=True)


class ProjectRequest(models.Model):
    project_title = models.CharField('Project title', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    project_from_user = models.ForeignKey('users.ProjectUser', related_name='request_user', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    project_to_user = models.ForeignKey('users.ProjectUser', related_name='request_to_user', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    project_details = models.TextField(name='project_details')
    request_status = models.IntegerField(choices=[0, 1, 2], default=0)
```

This is the query that I have used

```
query_set = ProjectUser.objects.prefetch_related('connect_from_user', 'request_user')
if months:
    today = datetime.date(datetime.now())
    gt_date = today - timedelta(days=30*int(months))
    self.gt_date = gt_date

if request_type == 'requester':
    query_set = query_set.filter(request_user__request_status=2, request_user__project_to_user=request.user)
    if months:
        query_set = query_set.filter(request_user__created_date__date__gt=gt_date)
elif request_type == 'connector':
    query_set = query_set.filter(connect_from_user__to_user=request.user)
    if months:
        query_set = query_set.filter(connect_from_user__created_date__date__gt=gt_date)
elif request_type == 'both':
    request_query_set = query_set.filter(request_user__request_status=2, request_user__project_to_user=request.user)
    connect_query_set = query_set.filter(connect_from_user__to_user=request.user)
    if months:
        request_query_set = request_query_set.filter(request_user__created_date__date__gt=gt_date)
        connect_query_set = connect_query_set.filter(connect_from_user__created_date__date__gt=gt_date)
    query_set = request_query_set | connect_query_set
```

Everything was working fine but the condition *months=5, request_type='both'* is causing the Postgres to take so many resources (100% CPU for more than 5 minutes)

The below code section is causing this issue

```
request_query_set = request_query_set.filter(request_user__created_date__date__gt=gt_date)
connect_query_set = connect_query_set.filter(connect_from_user__created_date__date__gt=gt_date)
```

Is there any other method that I can use to get the query that I need. I just need to filter according to the months of the created date from both models.

Comment: Django version is 2.1.5

Comment: When I changed query_set  = request_query_set | connect_query_set with request_query_set.union(follow_query_set) the query is executed fast